# Restrict Groups in django admin for staff user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am trying to restrict the groups populated for staff users, such that a  user X( staff ) is able to view and edit only those groups which X is a member.

I am able to filter groups populated on admin/auth/group/ by registering the new class.

```
class RestrictGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super(RestrictGroupAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return request.user.groups.all()
```

With this approach I am able to filter out groups on admin/auth/group/, but unable to filter out the list of available groups in user edit admin page .

Is there a way to filter the available groups in user edit page?

Also, is the above approach to restrict groups is correct ?

Can we extend the same approach to users and permissions as well ?

**PS:** Django version 1.11.1